# Название нашей команды — «Незелёные / Не зелёные»

Tags: орфография, частица-не, слитно-раздельно

Как правильно?

> Название нашей команды — «Незелёные / Не зелёные».

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно: ***Название нашей команды — "Незелёные".***

Отрицание в названии не используется. Названия пишутся в авторской (более свободной) форме.

**Примеры:**

*— Название нашей команды — **"Незеленые"!***

*— Елки **зеленые**, опять эти **зеленые** в top class записались?*

Статья  **[Незеленые зеленые](https://dzen.ru/a/ZD_-5zD5JhjLDq9M)**

**Словарь**

**ЗЕЛЁНЫЙ,** 1. **Один из цветов** солнечного спектра, находящийся между жёлтым и голубым; цвета травы, зелени. З. цвет. З-ая краска. 6. **Очень юный; неопытный по молодости.** З. юнец. З. гимназист. З-ая молодёжь. З. возраст. З-ая пора. З-ая юность.

Comment: Плюс от меня, очень полезный ответ.