# не с относительными прилагательными

Tags: частица

Почему "неженатый парень", "незамужняя девушка" пишутся слитно, если это относительные прилагательные.

Comment: Вопрос по теме  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476014/Папа-купил-не-зелёную-чечевицу-незелёную-чечевицу/476019?noredirect=1#comment515791_476019

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476021/Название-нашей-команды-Незелёные-Не-зелёные

Comment: Неженатый потому что холостой, холостой парень, а какой ещё? А незамужняя девушка - это штамп. Девушка она как бы это не замужем, очевидно, а замужем уже не девушка, а жена. "незамужняя заботится о Господнем, как угодить Господу, чтобы быть святою и телом и духом; а замужняя заботится о мирском, как угодить мужу." - название человека, поэтому слитно, это не совсем прилагательное. "— Хорошо, оставим этот вопрос, Так, по-вашему, только замужняя женщина достигает своего назначения? — Да, незамужняя — незрелый плод..." Неженатый > парень, незамужняя > чем женщина по смысловой нагрузке.

Comment: @Буратино Домострой какой-то...)) Это когда было-то. А теперь, может, наоборот)

Comment: Почему вы не ставите вопросительный знак в конце вопросительного предложения?

Comment: Это вы кому? Вы почему почту не пишете? А пробелы все на месте?  А то еще дефис вместо тире пишут. Вы проверяйте.

Comment: Риторическое утверждение это.

Comment: @Буратино  Смешно! Мне нравится инверсия в ваших предложениях, скоро так же буду писать)

Comment: @Sharon Домострой и знание женской физиологии дает чудовищный результат. Учите домострой - научитесь инверсии, женскую физиологию вы и так знаете). А вообще,  при инверсии можно не ставить тире, то есть фраза такая не является определением, а является утверждением, тоже сродни вопросам риторическим.

Comment: Ну да, стилистическая фигура.  Авторская находка или видели где?

Comment: @Sharon ну видеть-то я видел, в Библии так любят писать, имя его, вместо его имя и тп., но подумал об этом незадолго до нашей беседы сегодня. Хотя, наверное, сам так пишу время от времени.

Comment: @Буратино  Фонетические Игры  // вижу я в этом)  Вот ваше предложение:  (1) Риторическое утверждЕние  // это. Убираем инверсию:  (2) Это // риторическое утверждение .  Предложение делится не две части: повышение тона — пауза — понижение тона. При нормальном порядке слов (2) сочетание попадает по понижение голоса в конце фразы, а при инверсии (1)  — под повышение. Вторая часть короткая, фраза  как бы обрывается на повышении тона, что привлекает внимание, выделяет сказанное. Поэтому это стилистическая фигура)

Comment: @Sharon наверное, но я бы не членил "Риторическое утверждЕние // это", скорее вот так "риторическое утверждЕние-этэ..", без паузы одним словом, а в первом варианте там полноценная пауза.

Comment: @Буратино Нет вопросов. В первой части вы ставите ударение по правилам (в конце фразы), но оно идет на повышении тона, а не на понижении, вот что необычно и интересно, А конечное это похоже на присоединение. Фонетика дает вам любые краски. Рисуй, художник!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пишутся слитно с не прилагательные, которые в сочетании с не приобретают противоположное значение; обычно такие слова можно заменить синонимами без не. Например: небольшой (ср. : маленький) , неженатый (ср. : холостой) , ненастоящий (ср. : ложный, притворный) .

Comment: Неженатый необязательно же холостой.

Comment: Хорошо, вот. **другие синонимы**, свободный, разведенный, одинокий

Comment: @ТатьянаАлексеевна Посмотрите дополнительно к этому ответу § 148, пункт.2  http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=79#pp79

Comment: @Sharon Что значит "новое понятие"?

Comment: То, которое имеет собственное определение в словаре. Вот вам дали ряд синонимов, и все они раскрывают это новое понятие

Comment: @sharon Почему тогда везде пишут, что с относительными надо писать разлельно?

Comment: Есть разница: обычно/как правило НЕ пишется  раздельно (формулировка Розенталя), но частные случаи всегда возможны. Вот у Лопатина уже есть корректирующий материл по таким случаям.

Comment: @Sharon А почему не подразуемевающееся противопоставление? Эта девушка не замужняя.

Comment: Это по контексту можно определить, пример из Нацкоруса:  "Нет, вы не замужняя женщина, вы — разводка, даже больше того: вы — вдова",  Но такое встречается редко.